# How to reference a Many to Many field in django that takes various Users

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Im building a Django model for creating Polls with various users where they can invite each other.

Models.py

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class DateTimeRange(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()

class AvailabilityPoll(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    duration = models.TimeField()
    datetime_ranges = models.ManyToManyField(DateTimeRange, related_name='datetime_ranges')
    deadline = models.DateTimeField()
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(Participant, related_name='participants')

    def is_expired(self):
        return self.deadline <= timezone.now()

    def get_participant_count(self):
        return self.participants.count()
```

I made a view and a serializer for a POST api using Django Rest Framework to create this view:
Views.py

```
class AvailabilityPollView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    serializer_class = AvailabilityPollSerializer

    @swagger_auto_schema(request_body=serializer_class, responses={201: serializer_class})
    def post(self, request):
        poll = request.data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=poll)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from polls.models import AvailabilityPoll, DateTimeRange

User = get_user_model()


class ParticipantsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email']

class DateTimeRangeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DateTimeRange
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        range = DateTimeRange.objects.create(start_time=validated_data['start_time'], end_time=validated_data['end_time'])
        range.save()
        return range

class AvailabilityPollSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    datetime_ranges = DateTimeRangeSerializer(many=True)
    participants = ParticipantsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = AvailabilityPoll
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        datetime_ranges_data = validated_data.pop('datetime_ranges')
        participants_data = validated_data.pop('participants')
        poll = AvailabilityPoll.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for range in datetime_ranges_data:
            poll.datetime_ranges.add(DateTimeRangeSerializer.create(self, validated_data=range))

        for participant in participants_data:
            user = User.objects.get(email=participant['email'])
            poll.users.add(user)

        return poll
```

When I try to test it out in postman with users I already created as the participants I get an error saying that the users with this email already exists. What am I doing wrong here? How can I reference multiple existing users to a single Poll model? I am using a custom User Model that takes email as primary field.

Json post body:

```
{
    "name":  "TestPoll",
    "description": "Test",
    "datetime_ranges" : [
        {
            "start_time": "2023-05-01T10:00:00Z",
            "end_time": "2023-05-01T12:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "start_time": "2023-05-01T14:00:00Z",
            "end_time": "2023-05-01T16:00:00Z"
        }
    ],
    "participants": [
        {
            "email": "test@test.com"
        },
        {
            "email" : "test2@test2.com"
        }
    ],
    "duration": "1:00:00",
    "deadline": "2023-05-01T00:00:00Z"
}
```

I tried creating this participants model and using a foreign key to reference it. I was expecting to create a Polls object that reference the users as its participants.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Apparently it is trying to create new users because it only return is tthat:


    "participants": [
        {
            "email": [
                "user with this email already exists."
            ]
        },
        {
            "email": [
                "user with this email already exists."
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely what you want to do is work with a [**`SlugRelatedField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield):

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.serializers import SlugRelatedField


class AvailabilityPollSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    datetime_ranges = DateTimeRangeSerializer(many=True)
    participants = SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='email', queryset=User.objects.all(), many=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = AvailabilityPoll
        fields = '__all__'
```

So it is not necessary to do the `.create` logic. Django will automatically look up the items and add these.

The data is also more concise:

```
{
    "name":  "TestPoll",
    "description": "Test",
    "datetime_ranges" : [
        {
            "start_time": "2023-05-01T10:00:00Z",
            "end_time": "2023-05-01T12:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "start_time": "2023-05-01T14:00:00Z",
            "end_time": "2023-05-01T16:00:00Z"
        }
    ],
    "participants": ["test@test.com", "test2@test2.com"],
    "duration": "1:00:00",
    "deadline": "2023-05-01T00:00:00Z"
}
```

Since your availability poll however has a duration, it is not entirely clear to me why the ranges have both a start and end date. By specifying only a start timestamp, we can derive the end timestamp, just by adding the duration to it.